# my google maps custome marker wont show in my wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I can't seem to get my custom marker to show in my google custom map! it used to work a few days ago when I was editing on localhost and used an absolute link for it. the site is in wordpress and Im using a custom styled maps api key and still using absolute link for the icon.

page is at: http://www.smugglersrest.com.au/contact/.

custom marker is located at: http://www.smugglersrest.com.au/wp-content/themes/wpsmugglersrest/img/marker.png

I've also got the google maps api stored in the js folder because i wasn't sure how to enqueue external scripts via the functions.php file and the custom parts of the map & marker call stored in another map.js file and call in via the functions.php
can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

The external file calls to .js files .. mainly the main.js is giving a 403 forbidden error. If you sort that out, I think your marker will show properly.